# Cannot start virgo server if 8dot3name is disabled for disk where virgo is installed

Tags: java, eclipse-virgo

I'm trying to start Eclipse Virgo Server on Windows 2012 Server env. The disk I'm trying to install to has disabled 8dot3name option and there is no possibility to enable it.

Here is the exception I get after running startup.bat

```
 The activator org.springframework.osgi.extender.internal.activator.ContextLoaderListener for bundle org.springframework.osgi.extender is invalid
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:156)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:751)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:370)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:284)
at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.core.internal.StandardBundleStarter.start(StandardBundleStarter.java:57)
at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.core.internal.StandardBundleStarter.start(StandardBundleStarter.java:45)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:307)
at org.springframework.osgi.service.importer.support.internal.aop.ServiceInvoker.doInvoke(ServiceInvoker.java:58)
at org.springframework.osgi.service.importer.support.internal.aop.ServiceInvoker.invoke(ServiceInvoker.java:62)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131)
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.osgi.service.importer.support.LocalBundleContextAdvice.invoke(LocalBundleContextAdvice.java:59)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131)
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy61.start(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.artifact.internal.bundle.StandardBundleDriver.startBundle(StandardBundleDriver.java:168)
... 12 common frames omitted
Caused by:     org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.osgi.framework.ExtendedClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.osgi.extender.internal.activator.ContextLoaderListener in KernelBundleClassLoader: [bundle=org.springframework.osgi.extender_1.2.1]
at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.userregion.internal.equinox.KernelBundleClassLoader.loadClass(KernelBundleClassLoader.java:139)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.loadClass(BundleLoader.java:338)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.loadClass(BundleHost.java:232)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:149)
... 36 common frames omitted
```

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.osgi.extender.internal.activator.ContextLoaderListener
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:506)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.userregion.internal.equinox.KernelBundleClassLoader.loadClass(KernelBundleClassLoader.java:135)
    ... 40 common frames omitted

First idea was wrong classpath, but this lib is present.

I have idea, that I need to input "" somewhere in path. But can't find the place =(

Thank you for help!

Dmitriy G.

Comment: Well, according to https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=337679
there is a restriction in virgo for full pathes with whitespaces